# Unable to save multiple models with single form using fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, carrierwave, fields-for

I have an application which have **Deal** model and **Picture** model.I tried to update these two models with single form using fields_for tag,but 
**Deal model** only getting updated(parent model) but not **Picture model**.
I am using **carrierwave** for image upload.

**Deal.rb**

```
has_many :pictures,:dependent=> :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, :reject_if => lambda {|a| a[:image].blank?} 
end
```

**Picture.rb**

```
belongs_to :deal
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

**deals_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @deal = Deal.new
    @location = Location.find(params[:loc_id])
    2.times{@deal.pictures.build}
end

def create
    @location =Location.find(params[:loc_id])
    @image
    @deal = @location.deals.build(strong_params)
    if @deal.save
        redirect_to location_path(@location)
    else
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end

private

def strong_params
    params.require(:deal).permit(:deal_name,:category,:deal_type,picture_attributes:[:image])
end
```

**new.html.erb**

```
<h3>create new deal</h3>
<%=form_for @deal,:html=> {multipart: true} do |f|%>
<label>deal name</label>
<%=f.text_field :deal_name%>
<label>category</label>
<%=f.text_field :category%>
<label>type</label>
<%=f.text_field :deal_type%>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:loc_id, @location.id) %>

<%=f.fields_for :pictures do |builder|%>
<%=builder.file_field :image%>
<%end%>

<%=f.submit :submit%>
<%end%>
```

There is no problem with **carrierwave** I tested it by adding a new image column to Deal model.It works fine.

Is there anything i am missing.Help me.Thanks in advance.

**console log**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"gw7iEC+Q4qX0X69yIoqBr/RyX5dAfePqXkBYhGWM1/C/SMugfWbYFoYzm/pQ2Rn3CzMkPtD3Vwqvr4bZjYcgGA==", "deal"=>{"deal_name"=>"stackover", "category"=>"dsfwerdsf", "deal_type"=>"sdfewer", "pictures_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f1892c180c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151021-12944-11d4ykd.png>, @original_filename="Screenshot from 2015-10-16 18:55:40.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"deal[pictures_attributes][0][image]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2015-10-16 18:55:40.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}, "1"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f1892c67e68 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20151021-12944-1liyrcf.png>, @original_filename="Screenshot from 2015-09-28 15:55:20.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"deal[pictures_attributes][1][image]\"; filename=\"Screenshot from 2015-09-28 15:55:20.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}}, "loc_id"=>"2", "commit"=>"submit"}
```

Comment: Looks like it should work - have you got any params / console logs we could see?

Comment: I'm guessing that you need to use `lambda {|a| a['image'].blank?}` since the params might have string and not symbol keys.

Comment: `SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "deals" ("deal_name", "category", "deal_type", "location_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["deal_name", "console"], ["category", "dsfer"], ["deal_type", "erwer"], ["location_id", 5], ["created_at", "2015-10-21 10:55:09.335330"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-21 10:55:09.335330"]]`

Comment: Thats what they do on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html. You could check by doing `lambda {|a| abort a.inspect }`

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: @max I tried with `lambda {|a| a['image'].blank?}` but didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you are using:

```
<%= f.fields_for :pictures do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.file_field :image %>
<% end %>
```

Note that its `pictures` in the plural.

While in your whitelist your are permitting `picture_attributes`.

Try this instead:

```
def strong_params
    params.require(:deal)
          .permit(
             :deal_name,:category,:deal_type,
             pictures_attributes:[:image]
          )
end
```

Comment: I would recommend you take a look at https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide. Properly formatting your code makes it easier to spot these kind of misstakes. And it makes your fellow programmers happier.